# DBunit dataset: column regexp is a reserved word in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I'm trying to write an integration test with dbUnit for a table in MySQL that has a column with `autoincrement`.
The integration test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={
    JdbcRepositoryConfiguration.class, 
    DbUnitConnectionConfiguration.class
})
@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection="dbUnitConnection")
public class IntegrationTest {
    @Autowired private JdbcRepositoryConfiguration configuration;

    private Loader loader;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws JSchException {
        loader = new Loader(configuration.jdbcTemplate());
    }

    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("classpath:dataset.xml")
    public void loads() throws Exception {
        assertThat(loader.load(), contains("something"));
    }
}
```

I have the same integration test structure for a table that has no `increment` column and the test works just fine.
The `dataset.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <sometable 
        id="1"
        regexp="something"
        descr="descr"
    />

</dataset>
```

Debugging I can see that the actions taken to setup the data are to delete all and to perform an insert, more specifically:

insert into sometable (id, regexp, descr) values (?, ?, ?)

The error I get is:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'regexp, descr) values (1, 'something', 'descr')' at line 1`

For completeness, the `DbUnitConfiguration.class` has the following spring bean setup:

```
@Bean
public IDatabaseConnection dbUnitConnection() throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException, JSchException {
    Connection dbConn = configuration.jdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(dbConn) {
        @Override
        public void close() throws SQLException {}
    };
    DatabaseConfig dbConfig = connection.getConfig();
    dbConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new MySqlDataTypeFactory());
    return connection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out has nothing to do with the autoincrement.

The error was thrown because the column `regexp` is a reserved word in MySQL.

To workaround this, the dbUnit setup has to have the following line:

```
dbConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN , "`?`");
```

And the test just works now.